# let $k \in \mathbb{N}$, show that the cartesian product of $k$ countable sets is countable

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S$ be a countable set.  I know that for $k=2$, we create a bijective map between $S \times S$ and $\mathbb{N}$ in the following way:

Let $(x, y) \in S \times S$. Since $S$ is countable, there exist bijections from $S$ to the natural numbers $f$ and $g$. Define $h(x, y) = 2^{f(x)}3^{g(y)}$. This will serve as our bijective map between $S \times S$ and $\mathbb{N}$.

My question is, how do we prove it for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$?  Is it by (strong) induction?

Comment: $f$ is not a bijection.

Comment: $h$ is not a bijection.

Answer (score 0):

**Lemma:** $\mathbb{N}^k$ is countable.

**Proof:** Let $p_1, \ldots, p_k$ be the first $k$ primes. Then let $f(n_1, \ldots, n_k) = p_1^{n_1}\cdots p_k^{n_k}$. This injects $\mathbb{N}^k \to \mathbb{N}$ by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

---

Now since $S$ is countable, we have $S^k \to \mathbb{N}^k \to \mathbb{N}$.